# TFS automated deployment of web application

Tags: web-applications, tfs, visual-studio-2013, automated-deployment

I have a VS 2013 solution consisting of a classlibrary and a website.
The code is under source control in TFS 2013, and i want to setup nightly builds of the solution where the website is placed in a specific unc path which is a webroot on a test server.

Currently i have a build running for the solution which resultes in a output folder on the unc path named by the build definition and the build number format with a subfolder named "_PublishedWebsites" containing the website.
What i want is to have the website deployed with its name to the unc path without any build definition in the folder:

What i want:

\192.x.x.\TFS\WebApplication1\

Current:

\192.x.x.\TFS\Build definition one\Build definition one_20140408.29_PublishedWebsites\WebApplication1\

I suppose there is a simple way of doing this, but no matter how i configure the build definition or setup a custom build template, i end up with either no code being copied to the unc path, or some build error because i simple cant grasp how to configure the template.

There are lots of guides and questions here on stackoverflow for this, but i have not been able to find one for TFS 2013 which explains my scenario step by step.

So what are the steps for creating a TFS build definition where the result is a compiled web applicaiton placed in a specific named unc path folder?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to edit the `process build template` for this build definition.  You can use your current template by downloading it through the "Process" tab of "Edit Build Definition", it will be at the top.  Look for a line similar to this:

```
<mtbwa:CopyDirectory Destination="[UNCDestinationRoot + BuildDetail.BuildNumber]" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="234,22" Source="[BinariesDirectory + WebsitePathInBuild]" />
```

And change it to this:

```
<mtbwa:CopyDirectory Destination="[UNCDestinationRoot]" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="234,22" Source="[BinariesDirectory + WebsitePathInBuild]" />
```

Finally, use the modified `XAML` from your existing template to create a new `Build Process Template`.  Refer here for help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551.aspx

**Note:** You won't actually need a project to house your `XAML` as described at the link above.  You can just save the `XAML` and modify it with any text editor (though editing in visual studio will give you the flow diagram).